# tomcat 7 ssl config: can multiple certificates be created for an ip address?

Tags: ssl, ip, certificate, tomcat7

Referring to [Tomcat 7 General Tips on Running SSL](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#General_Tips_on_Running_SSL), in the third paragraph, what does the following mean?

> As a result, the request information containing the virtual host name cannot be determined prior to authentication, and it is therefore not possible to assign multiple certificates to a single IP address.

My question is about that last part...

> it is therefore not possible to assign multiple certificates to a single IP address

General question and I'm not asking specifically about virtual host name. Can I create multiple certificates with the same ip?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to get a certificate with multiple Subject Alternative Names, one for each name you intend to serve.

(The mechanism that allows for multiple certificates on the same IP address and port is Server Name Indication, a TLS extension that is only supported on the client side in Java 7. It is not supported in Java 6. It should also be supported on both sides in Java 8, although this would certainly require modifications to Tomcat to support it too.)

Comment: Err, you mean 'no, but ...'.